# singularity of $\cos ( z^{-1})/z^{-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find what kind of singularity  $f(z)=\frac{\cos ( z^{-1})}{z^{-1}}$ has.
is it removable, pole, or essential?
I have no idea .... having double fraction is very confusing.

Thank you

Comment: Deal with one fraction at a time. What kind of singularity is there in $\cos{1\over z}$?

Comment: Write the [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series#Principal_part) at $0$.

Answer (score 3):

It has an essential singularity at $0$. From the power series for  cosine we see that there is  a Laurent series expansion with infinitely many terms in  negative powers of $z$.

$z\cos (\frac 1  z)=z -\frac 1{(2!)z}+\frac  1 { (4!) z^{3}}-\frac 1 {(6!)z^{5}}....$